# .NET events in PowerShell

Tags: events, powershell

So there are plenty of examples out there using of how to use Windows Forms in PowerShell, which obviously rely heavily on .NET events.

In these examples, events are never subscribed to using `Register-ObjectEvent` but instead by doing something like...

```
$form1.Add_Load({ Form1_Load $form1 $EventArgs })
```

or ...

```
$form1_Load={ Write-Host "Hello, loading form!" }

$form1.Add_Load($form1_Load)
```

This seems far simpler to follow and code than using `Register-ObjectEvent` and then having to call `Receive-Job` to see if we got any events.

I'm confused as to what the difference between calling the method `$form1.Add_Load` and `Register-ObjectEvent -InputObject $form1 -Event Load` is, as well as to why in some cases it seems like calling the method doesn't seem to work.

For example, if I run the following code:

```
$timer = New-Object Timers.Timer
$timer.Interval = 500
$timer.Start()
Register-ObjectEvent -inputObject $timer -eventName Elapsed -Action {Get-Random -Min 0 -Max 100}
```

I get a job created and if I run `Receive-Job (Get-Job)` I get a list of all random numbers it generated since last `Receive-Job`, as expected.

However, if I run the following instead, I get nothing. No errors, no warnings, just nothing.

```
$timer = New-Object Timers.Timer
$timer.Interval = 500
$timer.Start()
$timer.Add_Elapsed({Write-Host (Get-Random -Min 0 -Max 100)})
```

What are the differences? Does this have something to do with Windows Forms not being used in the second example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short version: when `Timer.SynchronizingObject` is null, the method that handles the Elapsed event is called on a thread from the system-thread pool, but `Register-ObjectEvent` takes care of stuff like that ;-)

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timers.timer.synchronizingobject

You can also assign a form to the SynchronizingObject, and then use ShowDialog() to set the runspace thread as the form's UI thread and the events should run then, until you close the form and give up the thread again. (not terribly useful, I know).

I'm still trying to think of a way to just tell the timer to use the host's thread...

Answer (score 0):

When you use `Register-ObjectEvent`, you get access to the `$event` automatic variable, which contains a reference to the event that was generated / thrown. You can access details about the event that way, however if you use the `Add_*` or `Remove_*` .NET methods, then you don't have access to the event details, to the best of my current knowledge.

Here is the PowerShell documentation about the `$event` automatic variable.

> $Event
>
> Contains a PSEventArgs object that represents the event that is being
>        processed.  This variable is populated only within the Action block of
>        an event registration command, such as Register-ObjectEvent. The value
>        of this variable is the same object that the Get-Event cmdlet returns.
>        Therefore, you can use the properties of the $Event variable, such as
>        $Event.TimeGenerated , in an Action script block.

Comment: Thank you for the reply Trevor. I understand fully that `Register-ObjectEvent` gives me access to the `$event` object (though as shown above with `Form1_Load` function this can also be done via the `Add_<event>` method), but in my example above I am doing nothing with the `$event` variable in either of the examples, I am just sending something to the pipeline. I would expect the same results on both. As I said though, when I do `Add_<event>` I get absolutely nothing back.

Comment: The $event is available in the add_* handlers too, it's just called $_ instead... or, you could supply a param() statement to capture it. I can't figure out why add_elapsed isn't working here.

Comment: When SynchronizingObject is null, the method that handles the Elapsed event is called on a thread from the system-thread pool.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timers.timer.synchronizingobject